# getting different answer for sizeof(arr) in different scenario?;

Tags: c++, sizeof, arr

consider these two programs:

//////////////////////Program 1////////////

```
void print(int arr[])
{
 int *p=arr;
 cout<< sizeof(arr)<<endl; //// here it is 8 
}

int main()
{
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
print(arr);
return 0;
}
```

/////////////////////////////
///////////////////Program 2///////////

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
printf("%ld \n",sizeof(arr)); /// here it is 12
return 0;
}
```

////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` has *decayed* to a pointer type once it's been passed to `print`. So `sizeof` within that function yields the size of a pointer to `int` on your platform.

In Program 2, that decay has not occurred: the type of `arr` is an array of 3 `int`s. The size is `sizeof(int) * 3`.